# Consulta con INNER JOIN me devuelve campos vacíos

Tags: mysql

Tengo una cuestión que no logro resolver al hacer esta consulta con `INNER JOIN`:

*Aquí no me da error si me trae los datos que le indico:

```
 SELECT * FROM alm a INNER JOIN papas b on a.matricula = b.matricula WHERE a.matricula AND b.matricula = '12345';
```

*Aquí el error es que cuando coloco de matrícula una letra me regresa todos los campos vacíos:

```
SELECT * FROM alm a INNER JOIN papas b on a.matricula = b.matricula WHERE a.matricula AND b.matricula = 'PB12345';
```

Mi cuestión es en qué puedo estar mal o qué me falta para que me deje de hacer eso, cabe decir que al hacer la consulta con una letra y el número me arroja este:

> Warning: #1292 Equivocado truncado DOUBLE valor: 'PB212623'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No entiendo aun como quieres la consulta realmente... pero hasta donde se puede ver, quieres de la tabla A, mostrar los datos que coincidan con la tabla B, de la matricula B.X

Lo que sería algo asi...

```
SELECT * FROM alm a 
INNER JOIN papas b on a.matricula = b.matricula 
WHERE b.matricula = 'PB12345';
```

Comment: Justamente me acabo de dar cuenta de tu respuesta y lo resolví de esa manera, gracias por el apoyo!!